# Why does typescript dons't do typecheck on a 2d array?

Tags: arrays, typescript, types

I have this simple code to generate a 2d array:

```
type cell = {
  id: string;
};
const board: cell[][];
board = Array(10)
      .fill("")
      .map((x) => Array(10).fill(ANY TYPE CAN GO HERE WHY?));
```

When i fill the inner array I can put anything there without any problems instead of being able to put only type `cell` in there, why is that?

I understand that i probably need to give `Array(10)` a type but shouldn't typescript throw an error then? because cell is not in union with any.

Why is there no type checking in this scenario?

Is this to complex of a way for inferred types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array()` returns `any[]`, which TS accepts to implicitly cast to `cell[]` without complaining.

This asks 3 questions:

- Why does TS cast `any` to `cell`? That's by definition, and a fundamental part of TS. Nothing to be done about that but being careful.

Consider the similar situation:

```
type cell = {
    id: string;
};

const foo: any = "foo";
const c: cell = foo;
```

- Why does `Array(10)` return `any[]`? Because at this point there is no way to infer what the value should be. `Array<cell>(10)` returns a `cell[]`, though
- Why does `fill(obj)` return `any[]` rather than `(typeof obj)[]`? Presumably because `fill` mutates the object it's called on, so it does not change its type.

The main trap here is that `any` can always be casted to anything else. This is something to be actively on the lookout for, as it is one of the way that TS breaks its own typing system.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! I'll give it an implicit type